# Notice: Undefined index: mod in index.php

Tags: php

I get this kind of notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: mod in C:\xampp\htdocs\limpopo_basin\index.php on line 7

I tried to use the `if(isset($_GET['mod'])` before the switch but is not working. Below is the code snippet. What could be the solution to this

```
<?php
//CONTROLLER FILE
//include config file
session_start();
require_once 'config.inc.php';

switch($_GET['mod'])
{
    case 'home':
    {
        include 'modules/home.php';
        break;
    }
    case 'sea':
    {
        include 'modules/search.php';
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        include 'modules/home.php';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do `print_r($_GET)` and see if it has `mod` value.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the

```
switch($_GET['mod'])
{
    ...
```

with:

```
$mod = isset($_GET['mod']) ? $_GET['mod'] : '';
switch($mod)
{
    ...
```

This will first try to get the value of `$_GET['mod']` and when that GET parameter was not set, it will fall back to an empty string—which will then later trigger your switch’s default case.

Comment: Thanx Poke. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the if before, you want to wrap the switch in the if.

```
if(isset($_GET['mod']) {
    switch($_GET['mod'])
    {
    \\all your cases
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do something like what poke shows or: `if(isset($_GET['mod']) { //your switch and all the cases }`

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thats what I did. Thank you very much